# Keeping Windows10 snipping tool snip-ready

Tags: windows

I miss the one-click-snipping tool of Win7. In my attempt to reproduce that
readiness-to-snip in Win10, I let a batch file launch snipping tool at
Windows boot, so that when I want to use it, I just click on NEW in the
open snipping tool. That works brilliantly only ONCE, because, once used,
the snipping tool window closes. The context menu of the snipping tool icon in the open snipping tool window includes 'pin to desktop', but even if that is clicked, snipping tool still closes after first use.

So now I am on the hunt for a technique that will either KEEP snipping tool open, or automatically relaunch it after use.

Comment: there are many other (possibly better) snipping tools available. e.g. http://getgreenshot.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Windows logo key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to take a screenshot similarly how you do it with snipping tool (highlight part of screen) and paste it after using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

(https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts)

It works for me in Windows 10 1803, I don't know since when it's available.